# key-repetition for multiple keys in c

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

I was wondering if it was possible to change the key repetition behaviour(on Linux) in such a way that instead of it starting to spam one key as input it goes through all the pressed keys instead (perhaps system("something")?) So instead of when pressing two keys the keys going "wssssssssss", it should go like "wswswswswswsws" instead.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  That functionality is deeply buried in the operating system.  I suppose it might be possible to write some code that somehow disables the key repetition behavior and substitutes your own, but why would you want to?

Comment: This looks like an [XY-problem][1]
  [1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you implement an Input Event daemon that grabs (for exclusive access) that keyboard input event device, and produces suitable autorepeat events for keys being pressed long enough, emitting press, autorepeat, and release events back to the system via the uinput device.

I am not aware of anything that already does that, but I estimate it would be less than 500 lines of code in C to implement such a daemon.  Such a daemon would need superuser privileges ("run as root"), though.

For command-line game or utility that needs to detect multiple keypresses, using ncurses is way simpler.  For graphical applications, the widget toolkit (GTK+, Qt, SDL2, Tcl/Tk, FLTK, and so on) do support multiple keypress detection natively.

If you wanted to write C code without ncurses, you can use termios to control the terminal interface, turn off echoing and line buffering, and achieve the same thing as ncurses – but ncurses also provides nice terminal output functions, and works on basically all terminals and emulators, too.